# django ошибка при записи - python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django

в файле models.py было:

```
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
    titleNews = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    textNews = models.TextField()
    dateNews = models.DateTimeField()
```

стало:

```
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
    titleNews = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    textNews = models.TextField()
    dateNews = models.DateTimeField()
    imgnamenews = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

и я написал -

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

потом -

```
python manage.py migrate
```

и все было хорошо но я изменил файл models.py на

```
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
    titleNews = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    textNews = models.TextField()
    dateNews = models.DateTimeField()
    ImgNews = models.TextField()
```

и написал -

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

далее -

```
python manage.py migrate
```

и батс ошибка:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, index, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying index.0003_auto_20190716_1950...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__index_news.ImgNews

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 327, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 286, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__index_news.ImgNews
```

Что мне делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1: убрать ограничение на значение `NULL` в поле `ImgNews`, создать новую миграцию и выполнить её

Вариант 2: очистить Вашу БД и тогда выполнить `python manage.py migrate`

Суть проблемы: вероятно, в Вашей БД уже есть ряд записей в этой таблице, вследствие чего, при изменении таблицы, Django пытается сохранить все хранящиеся там данные, изменив их в соответствии с новой структурой. А т.к. при смене типа поля он не может автоматически конвертировать данные в новый тип, он пытается оставить новое поле пустым в каждой записи и сталкивается с ограничением `NOT_NULL`.